# How can I gate a low voltage using a high voltage amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, signal, voltage-divider, attenuator

You can use a transistor as an amplifier to gate a larger voltage to the signal of a smaller voltage.  For example, an audio amplifier can take a ±2V signal and use it to drive an 8Ω speaker with a ±40V signal at 100W to a current of 3.5A.

How do you go the other way?  What if you want to have your output signal have a much smaller voltage?  Say that your signal is ±48V and you would like to drive a 1.44Ω speaker with a ±17V signal at 100W to a current of 8.33A?

What if your source signal has a considerably higher voltage?  Say mains voltage, ±170V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends a bit: Audio amplifiers are usually designed to have the least possible output impedance as technologically and commercially feasible – meaning that your +-170V-capable amplifier might well be able to drive a 1.44 Ω load. In that case, when you want lower output voltage, you'd just reduce the amplification, or the amplitude of the input signal.

But assuming that's not the case, you would need to *transform the impedance of your load*. For AC signals, that can be done with an output transformer: More windings on the high-voltage side, fewer on the high-current side. The transformer transforms impedance inversely to voltage.

That was a pretty commonplace necessity in tube audio amplifiers, where tubes aren't actually that great at amplifying currents, but OK at amplifying voltages. So, these very high-impedance sources, and needed an output transformer to drive the speakers.

In modern audio amplifiers, you'd typically try to avoid that – audio-frequency transformers designed for higher currents than even cheap semiconductor output stages can manage themselves tend to become expensive.

In RF circuitry, the need for impedance matching becomes ubiquitous, but also, there start to be more alternatives for impedance matchers - discrete element networks, microstrip line transformers, coax configurations…

Answer (score 3):

You added the **attenuator** tag, so you've got part of it.

Keeping to audio amplifiers, the input and output capabilities are going to be independent of each other, you design the input stage you need, and the output stage you need, and interface them together.

Let's take the example of a 1.44\$\Omega\$ speaker, ±17V, 100W, 8.33A. You would design an output stage to those specifications, that output stage is going to have a drive requirement, let's say it needs ±10V in to fully drive it, you then need to design an input stage that will take ±48V in and output ±10V. This could be a simple 4.8 : 1 resistive attenuator.

Answer (score 2):

> *What if your source signal has a considerably higher voltage? Say
> mains voltage, ±170V?*

You use a 10:1 step-down transformer to achieve ±17 volts at the output.

> *Say that your signal is ±48V and you would like to drive a 1.44Ω
> speaker with a ±17V signal at 100W to a current of 8.33A?*

That sounds like a sinewave to me but, it's still the same type of answer: You use a 2.82:1 step-down transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

1. Purely dissipative. Mains is rectified to DC and supplies the output transistors. They’ll will dissipate the (voltage drop * output current). In the case presented, the dissipation will be in hundreds of watts at full output power. You got yourself a space heater. And the output is galvanically connected to mains, so touching the speaker terminals can electrocute you. **Bad idea**.
2. A mains-fed simple D-class amplifier. Much less dissipation since the output device (transistor/mosfet) switches fully on-off and doesn’t act as a variable resistor. The “PWM” waveform from the output device is used to control the current through an inductor, and that current then is what drives the speakers. Still not galvanically isolated. Less heat waste, just as dangerous.
3. A low voltage supply - whether transformer+rectifier based or a switching supply - safely feeding a linear or class D  audio amplifier. **That’s how everyone does it** because it’s safe - there is no galvanic connection between mains and output, and the output stage dissipation depends on the class of the amplifier. Dissipation-wise, the order from worst to best is class A, AB , B, C, D.

> What if your source signal has a considerably higher voltage? Say mains voltage, ±170V?

How is that ever the case? Explain please. This just doesn’t arise in normal circumstances. If you want to turn audio on/off from say a mains timer, then the entire amplifier’s power can be switched on/off.

Comment: [audio event power amplifiers](https://www.thomann.de/intl/crown_xti_4002.htm) tend to be quite high-voltage, otherwise you won't be putting kilowatts through a 4Ω speaker… But you're right, if I use a kilowatt-amplifier, I will want to use the matching speakers, not something that basically explodes under power.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Exactly.